# Macro to read a cell value, find in a table if such value exits, if it does, delete table row and shift up

Tags: excel, erase, vba

Forgot the code:

It returns object variable error.
I tried to record a macro but Find doesnt function properly with copy and paste, and then, macro records the actual row I´m in, not a variable.

Instead of Find, I also tried " Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=x" but that would return Autofilter range class failed. I´m stuck.
Hope it helps.

```
Sub alta()
'
' alta Macro
x = Range("I3").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Find(What:=x, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("I3").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("I3").Value <> "" Then
        If IsError(Application.Match(Range("I3"), Range("B3:B20"), 0)) Then
            MsgBox ("No Match")
        Else
            foundRow = Application.Match(Range("I3"), Range("B3:B20"), 0) + 2

            Range("A" & foundRow & ":B" & foundRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Mr Portland. It worked flawlessly. I didnt know the foundRow line. The olny thing I forgot to mention is how to replace that deleted row with a new empty one, so I dont get minus one row every time I run it. In order to keep total number of rows constant. And then it should autofilter so the new one goes down and doesnt stay in the middle of the table. Was I clear? Thx

Comment: Hey buddy. Got that last part figured it out. Thx